# Weird (and annoying) screen flicker on Compaq Presario CQ50

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, flicker, presario

I have a Compaq Presario CQ50 laptop. It is running Windows Vista Home Premium and Ubuntu 14 LTS. I have a NVIDIA GeFORCE 8200M G. I installed 331.79 drivers for it (as recommended in another post) to try to fix a weird flicker I have. I have two videos which show two instances of this flicker.

https://mega.co.nz/#!o1BjjIZZ!uhxRkZpU5GodCJeaaycJjZ7ndnEe-6VRwT4wtcU9sxs

https://mega.co.nz/#!9tIFWSLT!xiJzJTQwygz7TsyXhQlJ9uzFa_VyJKKxZ21M8xi4Wbw

I tried failsafe graphics mode, which worked for a while, but now when I try to enter it, my mouse cursor disappears and I can't select failsafe graphics mode. I tried updating from Ubuntu 13 to 14, which worked for a while (25 minutes) and the problem came back.
It's really not the flickering that bothers me, although it's horribly annoying, it's the freezing up that really gets in the way. 
Is it a driver issue, or a refresh rate issue, or what?
Hopefully someone can help me.
M. Piercey.

Answer (score 0):

This flickering is a persistent issue; I've experienced it on a Compaq Presario and on a Toshiba Satellite. I've tried a few “solutions” which have not worked for me; maybe one of these will work for you. A) At a terminal, type gstreamer-properties; if nothing happens, install with sudo apt-get install gnome-media; once installed, try tweaking the video properties. B) On my Toshiba, I tried installing updated intel drivers using these instructions ([Ubuntu 14.04 - changing Intel graphics driver configurations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504307/ubuntu-14-04-changing-intel-graphics-driver-configurations)); surely there's something similar for your Compaq. C) I tried resetting the resolution and refresh rate as described here (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHZ5n9pHohI). D) I had some kind of success when I used nomodeset ([What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)); there was no flickering, but performance was slowed down in so many other ways that this “solution” is like shooting your foot when you have a toothache to take your mind off the pain in your mouth.

**

I eventually solved this issue by using a newer (3.18) kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well on my compaq cq60.
First, Purge the proprietary Nvidia drivers (if any)

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

Next, install Nvidia 304 drivers and nvidia settings

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304 nvidia-settings
```

Lastly, Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```